# How to get the number of years, months, days, hours and mins of a certain number of seconds?

Tags: algorithm, date, time, seconds

Given an arbitrary number of seconds, how can I get the number of years, months, days, hours and mins?

The algorithm should first compute the maximum number of years, then the number of months and so on...

What is an efficient way to do this?

Comment: Are you aware, that the number of seconds is not constant per year (leap-years), month (January vs. February), or day (leap-seconds and daylight savings switch days)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's mostly down to plain division. As you may know...

- A minute has 60 seconds: 
  `number_of_minutes := floor(number_of_seconds / 60)`
- An hour has 60 minutes: 
  `number_of_hours := floor(number_of_minutes / 60)` or 
  `number_of_hours := floor(number_of_seconds / (60 * 60))`
- A day has 24 hours (at least usually... see below.)
- A month has anything between 28 to 31 days.
- A year has 365 or 366 days, or [365.2425 days](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year) on average.

The last two I mentioned may require you to think more about the stated problem. Either you define an "average" month, which then allows you to say "*x* seconds equal *y* average months"; or you don't convert your seconds to months at all.

(Thinking about it, if you were talking to an astronomer or alike, they would probably tell you that a day is *not* always exactly 24 hours, due to the occasional leap second.)

Comment: Why the downvote? I'd appreciate to know so that I can improve my answer.

Comment: You should make clear what year are you talking about. The value you gave (365.2425) is the *exact* average length of the calendar year. That actual length of a calendar year is always exactly 365 or 366 days.

Comment: @svick: Correct. I didn't consider it necessary to be that precise, as my answer's whole point is making clear that months and years are *not* constant units of time. It's true that fixing a time interval (specified in [s]) in a calendar may actually make conversion to months and years accurate -- but the results may still be confusing.